# React.js render text as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

This is how the render code looks now (And I know it's unsafe to do so):

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid pages_container">
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.page.body}} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The question is how can I render it safely?

Comment: So if you know of a method, why not try it? Don't forget to link to the jQuery library. It's a very easy and common mistake for people to attempt to use jQuery and forget to include the library.

Comment: I've alredy tried it, but somehow it's not working. I guess It's because of my bad syntax.

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to display your attempts. Some people will use your attempt to debug, correct it and explain why it wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Reference https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>

render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid pages_container">
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(this.state.page.body, {sanitize: true})}} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v41brcpz/)