# I'm receiving some data in the form of text from API which has HTML tags embedded in it in ReactJS environment. I want to convert that text into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so i have got the data from API in state by 
`this.setState({ description : data.book[0].description})`. Now when i access it in return of the render function `<p>{this.state.description}</p>` this is what is printed on the screen  `"When Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince opens, the war against Voldemort has begun.<br /> The Wizarding world has split down the middle, and as the casualties mount, the effects even spill over onto the Muggles. Dumbledore is away from Hogwarts for long periods, and the Order of the Phoenix has suffered grievous losses. And yet, as in all wars, life goes on.<br /><br />Harry."`
I want the `<br/>` functionality where they occur not printed as such.
PS there can also be other tags not only `<br>`. Also i dont need a package to get installed i need a function to suffice my need

Comment: To render text as html you should use "dangerouslysetinnerhtml", please check this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850614/react-js-render-text-as-html and https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Use the functionality innerHTML.

```js
<p id='you-element-id'></p>
...

const element = document.getElementById('you-element-id')
element.innerHTML = this.state.description // you Harry Potter text
```

Use this after get payload for you state.

innerHTML method parses the text with all the tags.